# http post request doesn't work for my flutter app code

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I'm trying to do an HTTP post request to the postman URL. In code, I can't find any error but it doesn't work in the flutter app.

though the data is entered in the text box, the response is not showing in a flutter. i have attached the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6xEO.png)

**Request body in postman code attached.**

**This is the response body in postman:**
{[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxTzM.png)
"processingTime": 1,
"result": {
"id": "fa6a14d5-2888-4634-8158-efcaa0690211",
"noteType": "PRIVATE_NOTE",
"privacy": "PRIVATE",
"reaction": "NEUTRAL",
"description": "KUSHAN  1",
"status": "ACTIVE",
"author": "Test User",
"authorId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"modified": "2021-09-07T13:59:33.9926797Z",
"flagged": false
}
}

**This is my code:**

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

postData() async {
  try {
    var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse("https://zen-api-1010.azure-api.net/notes/v1/create"),
        headers: {
          "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "008c47b597e54aedadbd5e4d270b35ed",
          "Ocp-Apim-Trace": "true"
        },
        body: {
          "noteType": 0.toString(),
          "description": "KUSHAN  1".toString(),
          "authorReaction": 0.toString(),
          "privacy": 0.toString(),
        });
    print(response.body);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}

class NavPrivatePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavPrivatePageState createState() => _NavPrivatePageState();
}

class _NavPrivatePageState extends State<NavPrivatePage> {
  TextEditingController noteTypeController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController authorReactionController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController privacyController = TextEditingController();

  bool inVisible = true;
  bool isNotVisible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Private Note Auto Expand',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 191, 0, 1),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Visibility(
                    visible: inVisible,
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isNotVisible = !isNotVisible;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Create Private Note',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: isNotVisible,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: descriptionController,
                        autofocus: false,
                        onChanged: (text) {
                          print("Text $text");
                        },
                        minLines: 2,
                        maxLines: 20,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Enter your message here',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey[600],
                            fontSize: 12,
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: isNotVisible,
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        postData();
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Submit',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[600],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: isNotVisible,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          height: 130,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              ListTile(
                                trailing: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                      'https://images.pexels.com/photos/220453/pexels-photo-220453.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500'),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Text(
                                  '2 days ago',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey[800],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                  'This is a private note that auto expands based on the text entered. The background will determine the privacy level of the post',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    color: Colors.black87,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: This API is work on postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `postData()` with

```
postData() async {
    try {
      var response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse("https://zen-api-1010.azure-api.net/notes/v1/create"),
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "008c47b597e54aedadbd5e4d270b35ed",
            "Ocp-Apim-Trace": "true"
          },
          body: jsonEncode({
            "noteType": 0.toString(),
            "description": "KUSHAN  1".toString(),
            "authorReaction": 0.toString(),
            "privacy": 0.toString(),
          }));
      print(response.statusCode);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

The problem is the api accept the json data but you are sending the map which needs to be encoded to json first and secondly the header has two missing parameters.

Comment: First of all thanks for the comment. It's working properly. I noted your mentioned mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: happy coding enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making your `TextButton`'s `onPressed` an `async` method and try `await postData()` inside it.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. I add the async method & try "await postData(). but still, it same. Ï'm looking at a complete answer. Something missing in the code. I can't find it